# Execute Stored Procedure inside Quartz

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, quartz

I made an application where there is a scheduling function using Quartz. I use the scheduler to run StoredProcedure using JDBC template and SimpleJDBCCall. but I always get a NullPointerException error when I call method on it's repository.

This is my full code:

```
public class SimpleTableScheduler implements Job {

  @Autowired
  SimpleTableRepository repo;

  private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SimpleTableScheduler.class);

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
      log.debug("Execute Simple Table...");

      QrtzSimpleTable toSave = new QrtzSimpleTable();
      toSave.setFullName("Insert New Record");
      toSave.setJobType("Insert");
      toSave.setDescription("Insert new record at");

      repo.save(toSave); // error occured when call SimpleTableRepository -> Save(...) 
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ChubbHelper.chubbDebug(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my repository

```
@Repository
public class SimpleTableRepository {

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;


  public VmCommonResponse save(QrtzSimpleTable data) {

    MyJdbcHelper helper = new MyJdbcHelper(this.jdbcTemplate);
    simpleJdbcCall = helper
        .outParameter("P_RECORDSET")
        .mapTo(VmCommonResponse.class)
        .spName("SP_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TEST_INSERT")
        .build();

    SqlParameterSource inParam = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("P_NAME", data.getFullName())
        .addValue("P_TYPE", data.getJobType())
        .addValue("P_DESC", data.getDescription());


    Map<String, Object> map = simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParam);

    List<VmCommonResponse> result = (List<VmCommonResponse>) map.get("P_RECORDSET");
    return result.get(0);
  }
```

If I call the repository with Rest, it's works properly, but error when I call in Scheduler. Is anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NPE?

Comment: repo.save(toSave); Where is Repo is @Autowired SimpleTableRepository Class.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleTableScheduler is not a Spring Bean. You have to add an annotation

```
@Component
public class SimpleTableScheduler implements Job {
```

In Spring you always have to declare the beans either with an annotation or a producer method.